# ios xml parsing logic

Tags: objective-c, ios, xml, xml-parsing

Can somebody help me write the parsing logic for the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<countryArray>
    <bikeTypeArray>
        <dict>
            <BikeType type="3">Mountain</BikeType>
            <Country type="3">German</Country>
            <UnitSold type="2">1271</UnitSold>
        </dict> 
        <dict>
            <BikeType type="3">Road</BikeType>
            <Country type="3">German</Country>
            <UnitSold type="2">2271</UnitSold>
        </dict> 
        <dict>
            <BikeType type="3">Touring</BikeType>
            <Country type="3">German</Country>
            <UnitSold type="2">3271</UnitSold>
        </dict> 
        <dict>
            <BikeType type="3">Racing</BikeType>
            <Country type="3">German</Country>
            <UnitSold type="2">4271</UnitSold>
        </dict> 
   </bikeTypeArray>

    <bikeTypeArray>
        <dict>
            <BikeType type="3">Mountain</BikeType>
            <Country type="3">France</Country>
            <UnitSold type="2">271</UnitSold>
        </dict> 
        <dict>
            <BikeType type="3">Road</BikeType>
            <Country type="3">France</Country>
            <UnitSold type="2">371</UnitSold>
        </dict> 
        <dict>
            <BikeType type="3">Touring</BikeType>
            <Country type="3">France</Country>
            <UnitSold type="2">471</UnitSold>
        </dict> 
        <dict>
            <BikeType type="3">Racing</BikeType>
            <Country type="3">France</Country>
            <UnitSold type="2">571</UnitSold>
        </dict> 
    </bikeTypeArray>
</countryArray>















After parsing i need the result to be in the form of a single array as shown :
po countryArray 

     <__NSArrayM 0x82299d0>(
        <__NSArrayM 0x822abf0>(
          {
            BikeType = Mountain;
            Country = German;
            UnitSold = 4080;
          },
          {
            BikeType = Road;
            Country = German;
            UnitSold = 20017;
          },
          {
            BikeType = Touring;
            Country = German;
            UnitSold = 2035;
          },
          {
            BikeType = Racing;
            Country = German;
            UnitSold = 3703;
          }
         )
       ,
      <__NSArrayM 0x822ac50>(
        {
         BikeType = Mountain;
         Country = France;
         UnitSold = 2195;
          },
        {
         BikeType = Road;
         Country = France;
         UnitSold = 20191;
         },
         {
         BikeType = Touring;
          Country = France;
           UnitSold = 4138;
          },
         {
         BikeType = Racing;
         Country = France;
          UnitSold = 8378;
           }
            )


      )
```

So any hints on parsing please?I need a bikeType array inside a country array. dict should be in the form of key value pairs within each bikeType array.

Comment: Did you do anything/write any code/try a bit yourself to do the parsing ? If you need help regarding basic xml parsing, apple developer has some very good articles: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/XMLParsing/Articles/UsingParser.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002264-BCIIJEEH , http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html ,http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFXML/Tasks/ParsingXMLDocuments.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001232-CJBEHAAG

Answer (score 0):

Look at this xml parser -

http://www.tbxml.co.uk/TBXML/TBXML_Free.html

Answer (score 0):

### See This Example

```
- (XMLParserViewController *) initXMLParser {


    appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    return self;
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName
    attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict 
{

    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Books"]) {
        appDelegate.books = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Book"])
    {

        aBook = [[Books alloc] init];

    }

    NSLog(@"Processing Element: %@", elementName);
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {

    if(!currentElementValue)
        currentElementValue = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:string];
    else
        [currentElementValue appendString:string];

    NSLog(@"Processing Value: %@", currentElementValue);

}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {

    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Books"])
        return;

    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Book"])
    {
       [appDelegate.books addObject:aBook];        
          aBook = nil;
    }
    else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"name"])
    {
        aBook.name=currentElementValue;
    }
    else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"address"])
    {
        aBook.address=currentElementValue;
    }
    else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"country"])
    {
        aBook.country=currentElementValue;
    }        

    currentElementValue = nil;


    NSLog(@"%@",aBook.name);
    NSLog(@"%@",aBook.address);
    NSLog(@"%@",aBook.country);
}
```

---

I Hope this is Helpful for you..